# Detect SharedPreference changes from another instance

Tags: java, android

I making a very simple application, which simply can read and update it's SharedPreferences:

```
public class MyPreferencesActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
{
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener( this );
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener( this );
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        Log.d( "xcc", "onSharedPreferenceChanged" );
        reloadOpenGLES();
    }

    public void saveSomeData()
    {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().edit();
        editor.putString("MyKey", "MyValue" );
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

Everything is working great and onSharedPreferenceChanged gets triggered when I call the 'saveSomeData()' method, but the problem is - if I open multiple instances of the app, the 'onSharedPreferenceChanged' only gets triggered in the active application, but not in the one that's running in the background. How can I detect the change from another instance?

*Why I want to do this:*

I'm building a LWP which uses the GLSurfaceView. After user has changed the settings, the OpenGL needs to know that it has to update the scene because settings have changed, so I call reloadOpenGLES() when 'onSharedPreferenceChanged' triggers.

The strange thing is that if I have my LWP set as currently active LWP and then go to wallpaper settings and choose it again, change it's settings and 'SET AS WALLPAPER', the first instance of the LWP (the one that was set as my phones LWP) doesn't update the settings, meaning 'onSharedPreferenceChanged' triggers only in the currently active instance, instead of triggering in all of the instances of the same application. Resulting in user going to change some settings of already existing LWP and after updating the settings, nothing happens and he still gets the same old settings, unless he switches to different wallpaper and then back to this one.

In other words, when android changes the LWP, if previously set LWP is the same app as the newly set LWP, it doesn't seem to restart the LWP app, but instead probably triggers some kind of event. I though this event is the 'onSharedPreferenceChanged', but seems like I'm going at the wrong direction.

Maybe there's a better approach to this problem? Thanks!

EDIT:

I have updated my manifest as suggested by **adelphus**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.soft.test" android:sharedUserId="com.soft">

    <uses-feature
        android:name="com.soft.test"
        android:required="true" >
    </uses-feature>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" />

    <application
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <service android:name=".LWPService" android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.service.wallpaper" android:resource="@xml/livewallpaper" />

        </service>

       <activity
            android:name=".MyPreferencesActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.WallpaperSettings" >
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

but the problem still persists. Any hints please?

**Workaround**:
I was able to reload my settings on the following event:

```
public abstract class GLES2WallpaperService extends GLWallpaperService 
{
        @Override
        public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible) 
        {
           reloadOpenGLES();
        }
}
```

Still would like to figure out how to do it through onSharedPreferenceChange event from another instance.

Comment: You could try configuring "launchMode" for the [Activity manifest entry](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) - setting it to **singleInstance** to force one task only. Not entirely sure if it would work, but it might be an easy fix.

Comment: @adelphus thanks for the hint! unfortunately it did not work in my case. I tried singleTask as well, same result. I included the manifest in my updated question, maybe I got it wrong..

Comment: Maybe broadcast a message and listen for it.